# UITableView Rows not expanding

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

okay i've used this before but cant figure out why its not working now. is there another way to do it? or am i doing this wrong?

heres the code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, HeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if indexPath.row == selectedRowIndex && thereIsCellTapped {
        return 140
    }

    return 40    
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


    let cCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cartCell", for: indexPath) as? CartCell


    if selectedCellIndexPath != nil && selectedCellIndexPath == indexPath {
        selectedCellIndexPath = nil
    } else {
        selectedCellIndexPath = indexPath
    }

    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()

    print("did select")

    if selectedCellIndexPath != nil {
        // This ensures, that the cell is fully visible once expanded
        tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .none, animated: true)
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call `tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` between `tableView.beginUpdates()` and `tableView.endUpdates()`, No need scroll to selected row.

Comment: in swift 3 there is no "tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths" so i used "tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)" where you said to and still doesnt work. @lee5783